# How do I get the value from object(stdClass)?

Tags: php, parsing

Using PHP, I have to parse a string coming to my code in a format like this:

```
object(stdClass)(4) { 
    ["Title"]=> string(5) "Fruit" 
    ["Color"]=> string(6) "yellow" 
    ["Name"]=> string(6) "banana" 
    ["id"]=> int(3) 
}
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution, but I can't seem to find it... how to get the Color and Name?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Have you tried $obj->Title $obj->Color

Comment: It would be a bit more insightful if you post the code snip that you are using to generate that output.

Comment: Wait, what? You have to "*parse*" a string? Or is this an actual object variable?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can do: `$obj->Title` etcetera.

Or you can turn it into an array:

```
$array = get_object_vars($obj);
```

Comment: Thanks! $obj->Title does it for me.

Comment: stdClass objects can have vars not accessible with the array notation. Example using the DB facade of laravel (using psysh):
`>>> $res = DB::select("show create table test")[0]
>>> get_object_vars($res)
[
  "Table" => "test",
  "Create Table" => """
    CREATE TABLE test (\n
   ...
]`

The "Create Table" var is only accessible using `get_object_vars($res)`

Answer (score 16):

You create StdClass objects and access methods from them like so:

```
$obj = new StdClass;

$obj->foo = "bar";
echo $obj->foo;
```

I recommend subclassing StdClass or creating your own generic class so you can provide your own methods.

**Turning a StdClass object into an array:**

You can do this using the following code:

```
$array = get_object_vars($obj);
```

Take a look at:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php
http://krisjordan.com/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just need $obj->Title, but good to know the other info for the future.

Answer (score 8):

Example StdClass Object:

```
$obj = new stdClass();

$obj->foo = "bar";
```

**By Property** (as other's have mentioned)

```
echo $obj->foo; // -> "bar"
```

**By variable's value**:

```
$my_foo = 'foo';

echo $obj->{$my_foo}; // -> "bar"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved this issue by converting `stdClass object` to `array` using `json_encode` and `json_decode` like this:

```
$object_encoded = json_encode( $obj );
$object_decoded = json_decode( $object_encoded, true );

echo $object_decoded['Color'];
```

**Note:** passing `true` parameter in `json_decode` will return an associative array.

Answer (score -1):

`extract(get_object_vars($obj))`

will return $Title, $Color etc