# How do I access this JSON information (PHP)?

Tags: php, json, rest

I cannot access the contents within the orders array. I am currently doing this to no avail, and am wondering what I am doing wrong:

the $json object is a json response from a rest api.

```
$orderData = $json['orders'];
  foreach($orderData['orders'] as $order){
}
```

```html
{  
   "errors":[  

   ],
   "orders":[  
      {  
         "note":"",
         "estimated_shipping_fee":"0.00",
         "payment_method":"PAY_CYBERSOURCE",
         "escrow_amount":"12.95",
         "message_to_seller":"",
         "shipping_carrier":"Singpost - Normal Mail",
         "currency":"SGD",
         "create_time":1532064559,
         "pay_time":1532064618,
         "recipient_address":{  
            "town":"",
            "city":"",
            "name":"Teo",
            "district":"",
            "country":"SG",
            "zipcode":"41253",
            "full_address":"In some street somewhjere",
            "phone":"23154991",
            "state":""
         },
         "days_to_ship":3,
         "tracking_no":"",
         "order_status":"SHIPPED",
         "note_update_time":0,
         "update_time":1532082525,
         "goods_to_declare":false,
         "total_amount":"12.95",
         "service_code":"",
         "country":"SG",
         "actual_shipping_cost":"",
         "cod":false,
         "items":[  
            {  
               "weight":1.0,
               "item_name":"ABC",
               "is_wholesale":false,
               "item_sku":"5123433123",
               "variation_discounted_price":"12.95",
               "variation_id":0,
               "variation_name":"",
               "item_id":1126534500,
               "variation_quantity_purchased":1,
               "variation_sku":"",
               "variation_original_price":"12.95"
            }
         ],
         "ordersn":"3589290984539"
      }
   ]
}
```

Trying to access the variables directly, by say json['orders'][0]['payment_method'] is not working.

Comment: You used `json_decode`? Are you getting an error?

Comment: When you use `json_decode` (assuming, of course, that you did, in fact, use `json_decode`), the option to convert the result into an associative array is set, by default, to `FALSE`.  So if you just did something like this: `$json = json_decode($theResponse);`, you won't be able to access the result with an array syntax like `$json['orders'][0]['payment_method']`

Comment: $responseData = json_decode($server_output, TRUE); I specify this parameter to true :(

Answer (score 0):

convert it to array from json using json_decode(); then you can easily access it and if you want to access using jquery then just convert it object using jQuery.parseJSON();

Comment: This is really just a comment

Comment: $jsondata='[{"cid":"1234","city":"value1","district":"value2","state":"value3"}]'; // json format data
 $array = json_decode($jsondata); // json decode
//output 
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cid] => 1234
            [city] => value1
            [district] => value2
            [state] => value3
        )

)

Comment: And what is that?

Answer (score 0):

just use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for retrieving the object and then `$obj->note` or you can turn it into an array: `$array = get_object_vars($obj);` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956060/how-do-i-get-the-value-from-objectstdclass) .

Comment: This is really just a comment