# how to Get Data From object Form To Single String

Tags: php

```
stdClass Object (
   [records] => stdClass Object (
       [FULLTT] => Array (
           [0] => stdClass Object (
              [rs] => 75 
              [desc] => JIOPHONE ALL-IN-ONE PLAN Pack validity 23 days Total data 2.5 GB (100 MB/Day + 200MB) Data at high speed (Post which unlimited @ 64 Kbps) 100 MB/Day + 200MB Voice Unlimited SMS 50 
              [validity] => 23 days 
              [last_update] => 01-01-1970 
           )
        )
    )
    [status] => 1
    [time] => 0.0085189342498779
)
```

Here Is My Data How Can Get Value From This Object Please Help Me To Solve This

Comment: Hi i think the solution to your questios is in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956060/how-do-i-get-the-value-from-objectstdclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956060/how-do-i-get-the-value-from-objectstdclass)

Comment: use `->property` to refer to object properties and `[key]` to refer to array keys.